# PDO fetch() returning empty string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I am getting very frustrated. I have two functions which have similar "instructions" ie: return values from a users table in the database.

The second one works fine, however the first one is returning an empty value.

Here is the code:

```
public function ValidateUser($username, $password)
{
    $stmt = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1";
    if(!($grabUser = $this->db->prepare($stmt)))
    {
        return null;
    }
    $grabUser->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $grabUser->execute();
    $data = $grabUser->fetch();

    if(count($grabUser->fetchColumn()) <= 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    echo $data['password'].'s';
    if(!password_verify($password,$data['password']))
    {
        return null;
    }
    return $this->core->encrypt($data['password']);
}
```

I'm trying to display the $data['password'] on the page just to test whether it returns a value from the database, however it is simply returning empty, whereas the query *is* returning a column because it passes the

```
if(count($grabUser->fetchColumn()) <= 0)
{
    return null;
}
```

condition.

The $username and $password variables are both set, so they are no problem.

Just in case you ask, this is the function that *does* work properly:

```
public function ValidateFacebookUser($email, $fid)
{
    $stmt = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE email_address = :email AND connected_fb = '1' AND connected_fb_id = :fb LIMIT 1";
    if(!($grabUser = $this->db->prepare($stmt)))
    {
        return null;
    }
    $grabUser->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $grabUser->bindParam(":fb", $fid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $grabUser->execute();
    $data = $grabUser->fetch();

    if(count($grabUser->fetchColumn()) <= 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return array($data['username'], $this->core->encrypt($data['password']));
}
```

It does turn the username and password for that case. Why does it not work in the first function?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there data that returns if you use it in something like phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't mix up `->fetchColumn` and `->fetch` and with `LIMIT 1`.

What happens is that you already `->fetch()` the first row. After that invocation of `->fetchColumn()`, there's no more row to fetch.

```
public function ValidateUser($username, $password)
{
    $stmt = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1";
    if(!($grabUser = $this->db->prepare($stmt))) {
        return null;
    }
    $grabUser->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $grabUser->execute();
    $data = $grabUser->fetch(); // fetch once

    // no need to add ->fetchColumn checking
    $ret = null;
    if(!empty($data['password']) && password_verify($password,$data['password'])) {
        $ret = $this->core->encrypt($data['password']);
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out. Thanks :)
Instead of using empty($data) can you use count($data)?
Also if what you said is the case, how come it works perfectly with my ValidateFacebookUser() function, which has the same basic structure as the problematic function?

Comment: @zuc0001 yes you can use `count` directly on `$data` since it'll be empty when no rows are found. my suggestion is don't rely on `fetchColumn` on having to use `count()` at all since you're actually fetch the column values instead of the count `COUNT(id)`, you're comparing `'fetched_password' <=0`

Comment: I've implemented your code, however it is still returning $data['password'] as empty. It IS returning the column though, just not grabbing that password value!

Comment: @zuc0001 i don't know what inputs you have there, make sure `$data` isn't empty before reading the last `if` block with `var_dump()`.

Comment: I found the error! A function called $core->input() which I created was using PDO quote(), which wrapped the text in ' '. Therefore it was returning incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code is better still though. Do you know if PDO has an equivalent to Mysqli string escape?

Comment: @zuc0001 you mean `mysqli_real_escape_string`? no, just ditch that idea all together and use prepared statement, but i'd never recommend mysqli though, i've always been comfortable with PDO, just personal preference. glad this helped

Comment: Yeah, I checked over the code and am using prepared statements. No need for that anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the manual for [**fetchColumn()**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).  You can see that this fetches the next result set.  So if you've already called `fetch()`, there should be no next result set as per your code:

```
$data = $grabUser->fetch();
if(count($grabUser->fetchColumn()) <= 0)
{
   return null;
}
```

This will always return null with a `LIMIT 1` or single row result.